# Best way to clean balcony tiles in semi enclosed balcony that doesn't have drainage

Tags: tile, cleaning

I have a first floor semi-enclosed balcony that is at the mercy of the elements.  The tiles (porous stone) really need a good scrub with a water blaster but there is no drainage and I couldn't get a hose up there anyway.  Any suggestions on the best way to clean it?

Answer (score 3):

Some porous stone can be damaged by harsh cleaning chemicals. I would probably start with a stiff scrub brush on a broomstick, with a bucket of warm water and a bit of TSP (trisodium phosphate). Just don't use so much that you create standing water.

Let that dry then rinse with a sponge mop and clean water.

Comment: If the balcony's big enough to warrant it, she might rent a scrubber w/ a collection tank (to vacuum up the water after use).

Answer (score 0):

You could use household vinegar to clean it.
Try a small area to see if it would need to be diluted.
Straight vinegar may etch the stone and mortar joints.